# SSRS reports, header expression is not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I created a SSRS report, where a group is a broker. For each broker SSRS creates a separate page with a header. Now here is my my problem - on the header I have an expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!rec_type.Value = "1","Processor", "Client")
```

but the header always shows **`"Processor"`**, even when `rec_type = '2'`.

To create a header for each page I have these static Tablix Member parameters:

```
KeepWithGroup=After

RepeatOnNewPage=True
```

Are there any other properties I need to change?

Thanks,
zb

Comment: Try `=IIF(Fields!rec_type.Value = 1,"Processor", "Client")` if value is an integer it wont get picked up as parser will misinterpret it as a string.

Comment: The value of rec_type is created by Stored Procedure as char(1). I tried anyway to change as you suggested and it didn't work. I suspect that the problem is with creating headers on each page - SSRS creates the headers ones and just passes it to each page. It is my suspicion - but SSRS is innocent until proven guilty...

Comment: I tried to display as a header rec_type and a broker. For each page if shows the first broker and rec_type = 1. It looks SSRS is guilty.

Comment: Not necessarily, maybe your stored procedure is wrong? Try running it in SQL management studio or equivalent. The first part is ruling out SQL scripts, after that we go through SSRS piece by piece.

Comment: Guilty as charged.  Now I print a broker and rec_type in the header and added a column to show broker and the rec_type. I see on the header the same first broker and rec_type = '1', but on the report page in detail row I see different values for different brokers, as it should be.

Comment: Okay, so it was the stored procedure in the end?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column in the detail of your report showing the correct value then use that in the header. You can reference it as

`=First(ReportItems!textboxWithRec_typeShowing.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

It did not work. I added a column with rec_type and tried:

```
=iif(First(Fields!rec_type.Value, "DataSet1") = "1","Processor","Client") 
=iif(First(Fields!rec_type.Value, "DataSet1") = 1,"Processor","Client")
=iif(Fields!rec_type.Value = 1, "Processor","Client")
=iif(Fields!rec_type.Value = "1", "Processor","Client")
```

Each time the report header showed "Processor" only.

My solution - I changed the header to a fix value "Processor/Client"

zb

```
enter code here
```